# In Gatsby.js, specific style for a component only on a specific page

Tags: components, gatsby

I have a Header component that is used on a Layout component, which is used to structure the pages on my Gatsby site. There's a specific page where I need to give my header a different background-color. The problem is that there's no header component on that page, just the layout component. I've ended up making this work by adding a background-color prop to the header and to the layout. And I'm passing down the color down first to the layout which then passes it down to the Header...Is this the best approach? It doesn't feel great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `react-helmet` to add a class to your body on that specific page only. Let's say "dark-header", something like:

```js
<Helmet>
    <body class='dark-header' />
</Helmet>
```

Then, in your css code you could do something like:

```css
.header { background-color: #FFFFFF; }

body.dark-header {
    .header { background-color: #000000; }
}
```